# Moving files between users from shell in Mountain Lion

Tags: bash, shell, path, directory

I am working on a group of Bash shell scripts and have one of the scripts check if an update is needed. If so, it needs to copy files from my computer to others. In Snow Leopard I can just do something like.

```
account=$(whoami)
cp "/Users/Sleepykrooks/Library/Services/Program" "/Users/$account/Library/Services/Program"
```

But with Mountain Lion, even though the full path still would look like this, using the same thing leads to an error of not finding the folder or file it's looking for. However it does work if you use something like.

```
cp "/Library/Services/Program" "/Library/Services/Program"
```

This is where I am unsure how to use my path to copy my updated files to another user's path.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Does the folder exist in your Mountain Lion installation? You can't copy to a folder that doesn't exist; you have to create it first. The version of OS X should not affect this behavior, AFAIK.

Comment: Ah, I have it figured out. It got misled since if you command+i something on Mountain Lion it omits the user and volume from the path where in SL it includes all. I have been working between computers and had a confusion of locations that I missed. You are correct and it was pointing to a non existant folder. Silly error that I thought was caused by another issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you copy a folder in Unix, you usually need the `-R` flag. (See the cp manpage).

```
cp -R "/Users/Sleepykrooks/Library/Services/Program" "/Users/$account/Library/Services/Program"
```

Or, using the BASH shortcut of `~` for home directory:

```
cp -R ~Sleepykrooks/Library/Services/Program ~/Library/Services/Program
```

Normally, you should not be touching the `/Library` directory or the user's `~/Library` directory on the Mac. And, you should never touch anything under `/System` unless you can stare into a TV camera and say in an absolutely serious tone "*I'm a professional. Don't try this at home.*"

Comment: Thanks for the info! It's mainly necessary because these shell scripts are a part of an automator service and it won't show up in the contextual menu unless it's there from what I've seen.